# java sentence splitting error

Tags: java, regex, artificial-intelligence, stanford-nlp, text-segmentation

I want to split sentences from a paragraph using `java` language. Consider the following sentence.

> we decided to go to u.s.a, canada,africa etc... from our office. I
>   have only rs.1 lakh. So i called my dad and asked some money. he said
>   "No.I wont" and disconnected the phone

.

I used `stanford tokenizer`. Eventhough the sentence `we decided to go to u.s.a, canada,africa etc... from our office` is a single sentence, output showing that

> we decided to go to u.s.a, canada,africa etc...

is one sentence and

> from our office

is another sentence. Rest of the sentences are correctly splitting.

Please note : if the word is `etc.,` instead of `etc...` it is working correctly.

Is it possible to tell the program that the words followings `etc...` are the continuation of the same sentence ? 
I tried some other sentence spliting tools also. But the result is same. Please help.

Comment: make change in your sentence. use etc, instead of etc... its grametrically wrong

Comment: i know that sentence is wrong. Im asking Is it possible to tell the program that the words followings etc... are the continuation of the same sentence ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the replace function to replace ... With something unique. *+&1 for example. Then split the string and then replace the unique part with ... Again.